# Change Phone number placeholder and it's value on blur and on focus

Tags: jquery, html, placeholder, onblur, onfocus

```html
Phone:<br>
<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Please enter your phone number">
```

[The input box looks like this to begin with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6dv5.jpg)

[On click/focus, it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcQw3.jpg)

On typing numbers, the underscore should get replaced OR the numbers should get typed over the underscores

I have tried something like-

```html
<input type="text" name="theName" placeholder="Please enter your phone number"
  onblur="if(this.placeholder!==''){ this.value='Please enter your phone number'; this.style.color='#BBB';}"
  onfocus="if(this.placeholder=='Please enter your phone number'){ this.value='___-___-____'; this.style.color='#000';}"
  style="color:#BBB;" />
```

But as I start typing the phone number, I want it to get typed over the underscores and not like they're right now.

Comment: there is no simple answer to your question i believe , you can use libraries mentioned here : https://css-tricks.com/input-masking/ .

Comment: Input masking was exactly what I was looking for. Did not know it was know by that name. Thanks!
(I was able to solve it, and will post that as Answer)

Answer (score 0):

Insert these 2 Jquery plugins-

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
```

Rest of the HTML contains the following Jquery function and simple input box for phone number-

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function($){
 $('#phone').mask('999-999-9999', {placeholder:'xxx-xxx-xxxx'});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
  
<input type='text' name='phone' id='phone' placeholder='enter phone no.'>

</form>
</body>
```